# How can I find the differential in the Serre spectral sequence for this sphere fibration?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, spectral-sequences, fibre-bundles

Consider the assocaited sphere bundle $$S(E) \to \mathbb{P}^n$$ for the vector bundle $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus \mathcal{O}(l) \to \mathbb{P}^n$. Is there a way to determine the differentials
$$
d_4^{p,m}:E_4^{p,3} \to E^{p+4,0}
$$
for $m \in \{2,4,\ldots,2n\}$?

Comment: Doesn't the serre sseq for a sphere bundle reduce to the Gysin sequence? So, using cohomology instead of homology, the differential should be multiplication by the Euler class, which in this case is like... $klc^2$?where c is the standard generator in H^2 of CP^n

Comment: @DylanWilson Oh, apparently this is the case. Thanks for pointing this out!